# PAM authentication failed for user right after attach policy to IAM user with RDS permission

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I'm attaching an IAM policy to a User, so he can work with RDS PostgreSQL.
Actually to generate token to login to the PostgreSQL with this token:

```
aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST --port 5432 --region us-west-2 --username app_user
```

After attaching a policy, if I try to generate token, I've got error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "app_user"
```

But if I wait for about 5 minutes, I can generate token successfully with the same command.
The same situation with detaching the policy - right after detaching policy from the IAM User, I still can generate token and login to PostgreSQL, and only after about 10 minutes I'll get error, previously mentioned.
So, is it an expected behavior? I can't find any information about timeouts for applying policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is an expected behavior.
I've got answer for my question from AWS:

> This is an expected behavior as the IAM updates are evantal consistant. As of now there is no direct configuration setting influencing the timeout.